# GAE App with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I recently bought a Namecheap domain and have been trying to hook it up to my GAE website. The GAE URL is `domain.appspot.com` and it works just fine. I have followed the instructions outlined in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain but when I try to visit my custom domain I get an error saying:

`The webpage at https://www.domain.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have confirmed that domain.com and www.domain.com are both listed as custom domain names in the GAE console, and I've added all the IPs/CNAME stuff as specified. A `dig domain.com` command confirms that:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.com 1234 IN  A   216.239.34.21
domain.com 1234     IN  A   216.239.36.21
domain.com 1234     IN  A   216.239.32.21
domain.com 1234     IN  A   216.239.38.21
```

I'm wondering if this is a HTTPS issue because trying domain.com in Safari tells me that:

`Safari can't open "https://domain.com" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "domain.com".`

I don't want to get a cert for HTTPS but I don't see any way around the problem? How can I successfully use a custom domain with my GAE app?

Comment: It may take some time for DNS to update. Is it works for http://domain.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my `app.yaml` file. I had set `secure: always` which was forcing https, but I didn't have a cert. Now I changed it to `secure: never` to require http, and it should work fine.